# Cassandra Nodetool Repair error RepairException

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

When I run "nodetool -h 192.168.1.161 repair" on a node I get the following error. How should I resolve this? I'm running Cassandra 2.0.2.

```
ERROR [Thread-26] 2014-08-17 18:24:01,289 StorageService.java (line 2477) Repair session 8d2a1190-25aa-11e4-8a15-ff681618d551 for range (1844674407370955161,5534023222112865484] failed with error org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #8d2a1190-25aa-11e4-8a15-ff681618d551 on WIDGET_CF/STATS, (1844674407370955161,5534023222112865484]] Validation failed in /192.168.1.164

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #8d2a1190-25aa-11e4-8a15-
ff681618d551 on WIDGET_CF/STATS, (1844674407370955161,5534023222112865484]] Validation failed in /192.168.1.164

    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$4.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:2469)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #8d2a1190-25aa-11e4-8a15-ff681618d551 on WIDGET_CF/STA
TS, (1844674407370955161,5534023222112865484]] Validation failed in /192.168.1.164

    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.RepairException: [repair #8d2a1190-25aa-11e4-8a15-ff681618d551 on WIDGET_CF/STATS, (1844674407370955161,553
4023222112865484]] Validation failed in /192.168.1.164

    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairSession.validationComplete(RepairSession.java:152)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.ActiveRepairService.handleMessage(ActiveRepairService.java:188)
    at org.apache.cassandra.repair.RepairMessageVerbHandler.doVerb(RepairMessageVerbHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:56)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cassandra exceptions during repair](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246859/cassandra-exceptions-during-repair)

Comment: Long story short, your best option here is to upgrade.